# unable to load data into different tabs in Excel 2013 using VB6

Tags: excel, vb6, excel-2013, office-2013, vba

In my organization we have one old project/application which was build on **Visual Basic 6.0**

In that application we have export to Excel "button" where data gets populated into different tabs in spreadsheet with click. It was working very well with Excel 2010 and later until we moved to **EXCEL 2013**.

Issue: **We need data to get exported into 2 tabs in excel 2013 whereas its coming in 1 tab only.** I tried using package and deployment wizard and all possible help available. So far no luck. Please let me know if you have any questions or if I am not enough clear. Please find below my code.

```
Dim uprev As Integer
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlsheet2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean   ' Flag for final release.
Dim n As Integer
Dim n1 As Integer
Dim n2 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrevdate As String
Dim lastrevrow As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim previouspcno As Integer
Dim xlcol As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Dim dc As Adodc
Dim mrc As Recordset

Dim qpa As New QPArray
Dim Found As Long
Dim StartInd As Long
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim crlf As String

On Error GoTo errorhandler1

crlf = Chr(13) & Chr(10)


ReDim qs(10) As String
ReDim q(10) As Integer
ReDim hdr(15) As Integer
ReDim rev(10, 0) As String
ReDim part(0) As String
ReDim sl(nof) As String
ReDim cmpsql2(0) As String
ReDim deletedfromsql(3, 0) As String
Dim doThis As Integer
Dim iReturn As Integer

Dim revlev As String
Dim Date_Engr As String
Dim Date_Checker As String



'On Error Resume Next   ' Defer error trapping.
'Removed, not checking to see if excel is open properly
'Bert - 6/5/07
'Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'    ExcelWasNotRunning = True
'Else
'    MsgBox ("Please Close Excel before continuing")
'    Exit Sub
'End If
Err.Clear   ' Clear Err object in case error occurred.

iReturn = MsgBox("Please Close ALL Excel applications before continuing", vbOKOnly, "WARNING")

ExcelWasNotRunning = True


'fixwidth

Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass

'DetectExcel



Set xlApp = Excel.Application

'path(8) = "C:\SwitchGear\Files1\eng_prod\Jobs\cs01157\medt\"
If Dir(Defaults.medt & "\" & cs & sos & "mbom.xls", vbNormal) <> "" Then

    mbomflag = 1


    FileCopy Defaults.medt & "\" & cs & sos & "mbom.xls", Defaults.medt & "\" & cs & sos & "mbom.bak"
    Set xlBook = GetObject(Defaults.medt & "\" & cs & sos & "mbom.xls")
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
    Set xlsheet2 = xlBook.Worksheets(2)

    Do
        qs(1) = "1. Do not list changes on rev sheet" & crlf
        qs(1) = qs(1) & "2. list changes on rev sheet but do not increase rev level" & crlf
        qs(1) = qs(1) & "3. list changes on rev sheet and increase rev level"
        qs(0) = InputBox(qs(1))
        If qs(0) = "" Then Exit Sub
    Loop Until qs(0) > "0" And qs(0) < "4"



    If qs(0) = "3" Then ' up the revision
        uprev = 2
        revlev = xlsheet2.Cells(5, 3) + 1
        Date_Engr = Date
        Date_Checker = Date
    Else
        uprev = 1
        revlev = xlsheet2.Cells(5, 3)
        Date_Engr = xlSheet.Cells(16, 2) ' get the old rev number
        Date_Checker = xlSheet.Cells(16, 3)

    End If

    lastrow = xlSheet.Cells.Range("E20").End(xlDown).Row

    ReDim cmpxl2(0) As String
    ReDim cmpxl3(0) As String
    ReDim cmpxl4(0) As String
    n = 0
    For i = 20 To lastrow
        If xlSheet.Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve cmpxl2(n) As String
            ReDim Preserve cmpxl3(n) As String
            ReDim Preserve cmpxl4(n) As String

            cmpxl2(n) = xlSheet.Cells(i, 2) & " " & Format(i)
            cmpxl3(n) = xlSheet.Cells(i, 3)
            cmpxl4(n) = xlSheet.Cells(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i
    n1records = Adodc1.Recordset.RecordCount

    'If n > n1records Then 'it's been deleted from sql so find the part and add to xl revision sheet
        n1 = 0
        ReDim cmpsql2(n1records) As String
        With Adodc1.Recordset
           For i = 1 To n1records
               If i = 1 Then
                   Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst
               Else
                   Adodc1.Recordset.MoveNext
               End If
               cmpsql2(i) = !pcno
           Next i
        End With
        For i = 1 To n
            bFound = qpa.Find(cmpsql2(), Left$(cmpxl2(i), 4), Found, , 1)
            If bFound = False Then
                q(1) = Val(Mid$(cmpxl2(i), 6))
                n1 = n1 + 1
                ReDim Preserve deletedfromsql(3, n1)
                deletedfromsql(1, n1) = xlSheet.Cells(q(1), 2)
                deletedfromsql(2, n1) = xlSheet.Cells(q(1), 3)
                deletedfromsql(3, n1) = xlSheet.Cells(q(1), 4)

            End If

        Next i

    'End If

    n = 0
    Do
        n = n + 1
        If xlsheet2.Cells(n + 13, 1) > "   " Then
            ReDim Preserve rev(10, n)
            ReDim Preserve part(n)
            'part(n) = xlSheet.Cells(n + 13, 3) & "*" & xlSheet.Cells(n + 13, 1)
            If xlsheet2.Cells(n + 13,  > CDate(lastrevdate) Then
                lastrevdate = xlsheet2.Cells(n + 13, 8-)
            End If
            For i = 1 To 10
                rev(i, n) = xlsheet2.Cells(n + 13, i)
            Next i
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    If engr = "" Then
        engr = xlSheet.Cells(14, 2)
        chcked = xlSheet.Cells(14, 3)
    End If
Else
    mbomflag = 0
    revlev = 0
    If engr = "" Then
        engr = UCase$(InputBox("Enter Mechanical drafter's Initials:", "Enter Initials"))
        'If engr = "" Then Exit Sub
        chcked = UCase$(InputBox("Enter Checker's Initials:", "Enter Initials"))
        'If chcked = "" Then Exit Sub
    End If
End If

'Set xlBook = GetObject(path(2) & "vb\sql\ebomtemplate.xls")
Set xlBook = GetObject(Defaults.ApplicationPath & "\mbomTemplate.xls")
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
Set xlsheet2 = xlBook.Worksheets(2)



If revlev = 0 Then
    xlsheet2.Cells(14, 8= Date
End If
'xlSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = 50
If UBound(rev, 2) > 0 Then
    lastrevrow = UBound(rev, 2) + 13
    For i = 14 To UBound(rev, 2) + 13
        For j = 1 To 10
            xlsheet2.Cells(i, j) = rev(j, i - 13)
        Next j
    Next i
Else
    lastrevrow = 13
End If


'If uprev = 1 Then

'    xlBook.Application.Visible = True
'    xlBook.Parent.Windows(2).Visible = True
'    xlBook.Parent.Windows(2).Activate
'    xlSheet.Activate
    'bFound = bringwindowtotop(hwnd)
    'xlBook.Sheets(1).Select
    'ActiveSheet.Visible = True
    'xlBook.Application.DoubleClick
'Else
    xlBook.Application.Visible = True
    xlBook.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True
    xlBook.Parent.Windows(1).Activate
    xlSheet.Activate
    'DetectExcel
    'bFound = bringwindowtotop(hwnd)

'End If

'DetectVB
'Found = apiShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)


'DetectExcel
'Found = apiShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
Me.Visible = False



Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
'If uprev = 1 Then
'    xlBook.NewWindow.Activate
'    With xlBook.NewWindow
'        .ActiveSheet = 2
'        .Zoom = 50
'    End With
'End If
'xlBook.Application.Visible = True
'xlBook.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True
'xlSheet.Activate

'qs(1) = "03040609121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435"


cs = UCase$(cs)
sos = UCase$(sos)

xlSheet.Cells(10, 2) = cs & Left$(sos, 5)
If Val(framestr(0, 0, 15)) < 8 Then qs(1) = "2" Else qs(1) = "4"
xlSheet.Cells(10, 3) = "-" & Mid$(sos, 6, 1) & Right$(sos, 1) & "B" & qs(1) & "004"
xlSheet.Cells(12, 2) = Right$(sos, 3)
xlSheet.Cells(10, 6) = framestr(0, 0, 3)


'xlSheet.Cells(12, 3) = "0"
'xlSheet.Cells(16, 2) = Date
'xlSheet.Cells(16, 3) = Date

xlSheet.Cells(10, 4) = framestr(0, 0, 658) 'sold to
xlSheet.Cells(11, 4) = framestr(0, 0, 657)
xlSheet.Cells(12, 4) = framestr(0, 0, 656)
xlSheet.Cells(14, 2) = engr
xlSheet.Cells(14, 3) = chcked
xlSheet.Cells(14, 4) = framestr(0, 0, 655) 'for
xlSheet.Cells(14, 6) = framestr(0, 0, 661) 'purchase order
xlSheet.Cells(15, 4) = framestr(0, 0, 654)
xlSheet.Cells(16, 4) = framestr(0, 0, 653)

xlcol = "L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AAABACADAEAFAGAHAIAJ"

qs(1) = "L12:" & Trim$(Mid$(xlcol, (nof + 1) * 2 - 1, 2)) & "16"
xlSheet.Cells.Range(qs(1)).Value = " "


For i = 1 To nof
    xlSheet.Cells(19, i + 11) = i
Next i

For i = 1 To nof + 1
    qs(1) = Trim$(Mid$(xlcol, i * 2 - 1, 2)) & "12:" & Trim$(Mid$(xlcol, i * 2 - 1, 2)) & "16"
    With xlSheet.Cells.Range(qs(1)).Borders(xlLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
Next i

qs(1) = Chr(76) & "12:" & Trim$(Mid$(xlcol, nof * 2 - 1, 2)) & "12"
With xlSheet.Cells.Range(qs(1)).Borders(xlTop)
    '.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With

qs(1) = Chr(76) & "16:" & Trim$(Mid$(xlcol, nof * 2 - 1, 2)) & "16"
With xlSheet.Cells.Range(qs(1)).Borders(xlBottom)
    '.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight
```

I am aware VB 6 is outdated and not sure why they don't move to VB.NET. I would really appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you distill that huge amount of code down to a simple test case?  There's a lot to go through there (and some of it doesn't even seem like it would work at all)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is nothing to do with VB6 being outdated. The problem is that this code is unrunnable. I can only make a guess that this is some hacked version based on the real running code. I will make some guesses based on approximately what this code should *really* look like. However, it would be a good idea to provide the actual code.

By "tabs", I take it you mean "worksheets". I am guessing that they are called "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". So basically, only "Sheet1" is actually getting re-populated. "Sheet2" remains as it previously looked.

I would suggest that you put a breakpoint on the line:

```
Set xlsheet2 = xlBook.Worksheets(2)
```

See whether xlsheet2.Cells(14,8) evaluates to the date you expect to see on that worksheet.

After stepping through this line, ensure that *xlsheet2* actually points to the worksheet you expect it to. I would also put breakpoints on every line which reads or writes xlsheet2.Cells(x,y) evaluate it, and look at sheet2, ensuring that the value read or written back is correct.